# Accessing an array inside a JS object and removing an item from it by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an object where the values are arrays, like this:

```
{
  123456: ['apple','orange','banana'],
  987654: ['dog','cat','mouse'],
  112233: ['car','truck','bike']
}
```

and that I have access to 2 variables, itemID that has the key assigned to it, and the array index of the item I want to remove.
For example

```
itemID = 987654;
n = 1;
```

So the resulting object I want to get would be

```
{
  123456: ['apple','orange','banana'],
  987654: ['dog','mouse'],
  112233: ['car','truck','bike']
}
```

I need to write a function

```
removeItem(itemID, n) {
}
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
var obj = {
  123456: ['apple','orange','banana'],
  987654: ['dog','cat','mouse'],
  112233: ['car','truck','bike']
}


function removeItem(itemID, n) {
 if(!obj[itemID]) {
  return;
 }
 obj[itemID].splice(n, 1);
}

removeItem(987654, 1);
console.log(obj);
```

I'll add some explanation,
To access object by key you : obj[key];

Array.splice in this case,
meaning(splice(n, 1)) - take the item at index n and remove exactly one item from that index;

One more note :
when you access object the key should be a string
So I'l change 
`removeItem(987654, 1);`
To:
`removeItem('987654', 1);`

It will work in both ways thow.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `splice` method:

```
const removeItem = (itemID, n) => {
    if (!foo[itemID])
        return;
    foo[itemID].splice(n,1);
    return foo;
}
```

An example:

```js
var foo = {
  123456: ['apple','orange','banana'],
  987654: ['dog','cat','mouse'],
  112233: ['car','truck','bike']
};


const removeItem = (itemID, n) => {
    if (!foo[itemID])
        return;
    foo[itemID].splice(n, 1);
    return foo;
}

console.log(removeItem(987654, 1));
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since yours has a better structure and snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = /*ur obj*/
var itemID = 987654;
var n = 1;

removeItem(itemID, n) {
  let str = obj[itemID][n];
  this.obj[itemID] = obj[itemID].filter(item => item != str);
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="removeItem(987654,1)">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var data ={
  123456: ['apple','orange','banana'],
  987654: ['dog','cat','mouse'],
  112233: ['car','truck','bike']
};
function removeItem(itemID, n) {
  data[itemID] =  data[itemID].filter(function(value, index, array) {
   return index != n;
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```